# Set accuracy of random numbers in java?

Tags: java, random, floating-accuracy

I was wondering if I am able to set the accuracy of the random double numbers that I generate.

```
Random generator = new Random();
double randomIndex = generator.nextDouble()*10000;
```

That produces the random numbers within 10000.
How am I able to set the accuracy to 4?

Comment: What do you mean by "accuracy" of a random number? What do you want as output?

Comment: 4 digits after the decimal mark.

Comment: Then that is a formatting issue.

Comment: Please add details about *why* you want to do this, that will help you get a more accurate answer. As it stands, your question isn't quite specific enough for us to know what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things. First, you mean "precision", not "accuracy". Second, you need to clarify *why* you want to do this, because a correct answer will depend on it.

If all you want to do is *display* the numbers with that precision, it is a formatting issue. You can use, e.g. [`System.out.printf("%.4f", value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) or [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

If you are trying to to *generate* numbers with that precision, you could approximate by doing something like (rounding left out for simplicity):

```
double value = (int)(generateor.nextDouble() * 10000.0) / 10000.0;
```

Or if you want your range to be 0-10000 instead of 0-1:

```
double value = (int)(generateor.nextDouble() * 100000000.0) / 10000.0;
```

Due to the way floating-point numbers are stored, that will not be *exact*, but perhaps it is close enough for your purposes. If you need exact, you would want to store as integers, e.g.:

```
int value = (int)(generator.nextDouble() * 10000.0);
```

Then you can operate on that internally, and display as:

```
System.out.printf("%.4f", value / 10000.0);
```

Adjust multiplication factor above if you meant you wanted your range to be 0-10000.

If you are merely trying to generate a number in [0, 10000), you can use [`Random.nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) with a range specified, or simply cast the value to an `int` as above (optionally rounding).

Answer (score 2):

```
         Random generator = new Random();
         double randomIndex = generator.nextDouble()*10000;            
         randomIndex=Math.floor(randomIndex * 10000) / 10000;//this is the trick
```

Comment: @Ingo It *does* work, it's just that your original question was unclear.

Comment: All solutions, including my own, have the error that a double simply does not have "decimal positions", hence you can end up with numbers that print with more (or less) decimals.

Comment: @Ingo You *did* cover that by explicitly mentioning it in your answer, which is why yours is a good one in that respect. :) I also mentioned storing as integers, and converting on display, for exact precision in mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 4 digits after the decimal mark you can simply do the following:

```
Random generator = new Random();
double randomIndex = Math.floor(generator.nextDouble()*10000 * 10000) /10000;
```

Comment: Do I need to import anything by adding the "Math"?

Comment: @JiajuShen You could a) try it, or b) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random generator = new Random();
double randomIndex = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.####")
                .format(generator.nextDouble() * 10000));
```

Comment: That is a rather roundabout way of doing `(int)(value * 10000.0 + 0.5) / 10000.0`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
double result = generator.nextLong() / 10000.0;
```

Note, hoewever, that you can never be sure that the number has exactly 4 decimals, whenever you hit a number that is not representable in a double.

Anyway, the requirement is silly, because a double simply does not have decimal positions. Hence, to request 4 of them makes no sense.

Comment: It is worth noting that the theoretical range of this is -922337203685477.5808 to 922337203685477.5807; actual range and distribution susceptible to limits of `nextLong()` and internal representation of a `double`.